# Deleting first and last array element in one line?

Tags: ruby

How can I delete the first and last element in one line in a clever way?

I've tried:

```
names = %w[Go Go Go Power Rangers Go]
names.shift.pop
```

This fails because, I believe, both `shift` and `pop` return the value removed, which is then passed onto the following function, raising an error.

I also tried to make this work with `delete_at`, but it does not allow an array parameter and thus I get no further in my quest to make this a one-liner.

Any ideas?

Note: I value minimalism

Comment: Honestly, `names.shift; names.pop`. Stop valuing minimalism above clarity.

Comment: You can `filter` but really, why?

Comment: In some languages it's considered macho to be able to compress your code down to its most compact form, however you sacrifice readability and then maintainability when you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `names = names[1..-2]`, but you shouldn't. Just use `names.pop; names.shift` and be done with it.

Comment: why not? What is the problem with that?

Comment: It's much less clear than `names.pop; names.shift`, with no benefit. It's not faster, it's not shorter, it just *happens* to be a single statement, which is not inherently valuable.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There _is_ a benefit of `names[1..-2]` over `names.pop; names.shift`: the former is functional, as it does not modify its argument).  This has value in some scenarios.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what you want to do next? If you plan to use the first and last elements, then `pop` and `shift` are useful; if you only want to use what's left, then slicing is more convenient, as it saves two statements.

Answer (score 5):

```
_, *names, _ = %w[Go Go Go Power Rangers Go]
names #=> ["Go", "Go", "Power", "Rangers"]
```

Or if you already have the whole array as `names`, then:

```
names = %w[Go Go Go Power Rangers Go]
_, *names, _ = names
names #=> ["Go", "Go", "Power", "Rangers"]
```

Comment: Oooo, very creative. ;P

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
names.slice!(1..-2)
```

Really though, as others have said, there's nothing wrong with:

```
names.pop
names.shift
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like this solution:

```
 _, *names, _ = names
```

It is very cool, is not it?

Also, I would use another variable (funcional style)

```
_, *new_names, _ = names
```

Edit: Sorry I realised that @sawa already post this solution.